# Get data using the Id in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have some list of notes that I have stored in FirebaseRealtime Database and displayed in recyclerView.

By clicking on an item in the list, I open a fragment passing it a "guid". But since there are still name, description fields in this element, I want to display them in a fragment.

Q: how can I get the rest of the data from FirebaseRealtime Databse knowing the id?

```
class TargetEditFragment : Fragment() {

private var nameEditText: TextInputEditText? = null
private var descriptionEditText: TextInputEditText? = null
private var button: Button? = null
private var databaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null
private var presenter = TargetEditPresenter()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.getString("guid", "")
    Log.d("some", "onCreate ${arguments?.getString("guid", "")}")
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_target_add, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("targets")
    setupViews()
    fetchData()
}

private fun setupViews() {
    nameEditText = view?.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText)
    descriptionEditText = view?.findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText)

    button = view?.findViewById(R.id.addNote)
    button?.setOnClickListener { addTarget() }
}

private fun addTarget() {
    val name = nameEditText?.text.toString().trim()
    val description = descriptionEditText?.text.toString().trim()

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        val id: String = databaseReference?.push()?.key.toString()
        val target = Target(guid = id, name = name, description = description)
        databaseReference?.child(id)?.setValue(target)
    } else Log.d("some", "Enter a name")
}

//Here I want to get the data name and decription
private fun fetchData() {
//        nameEditText?.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(target?.name ?: "name")
//        descriptionEditText?.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable(target?.description ?: "description")
    }

companion object {

    fun newInstance(guid: String): TargetEditFragment =
        TargetEditFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply { putString("guid", guid) }
            Log.d("some", "argumeeents $arguments")
        }
}
}
```

Also my Target class:

```
data class Target(val guid: String = "",
              val name: String = "",
              val description: String= "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the guid then you can probably do something like

```
fun fetchData(guid: String) {
    // Attach a listener to read the data at the target id
    databaseReference?.child(guid)?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { 
            // handle error
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            // data here 
            val data = dataSnapshot.value as HashMap<String, String>

            val desc = data["description"]

            val name = data["name"]
        }
    })
}
```

the dataSnapshot will be a hashmap of String -> String with the name and description in it

Comment: i tried wrote something like this
`fetchData(arguments?.getString("guid", "") ?: "")`
but `fetch data kotlin.Unit`
and in `onDataChange` wrote smth like this: ` val userName = dataSnapshot.child("targets").value.toString()` 
but i think it s wrong(

Comment: @Morozov you dont need to get the child of the snapshot since your grabbing it from the child already, just get the value from it and you can cast that to a Hashmap. Ill update my answer to show that - can't test it right now because I'm at work but try putting a breakpoint and seeing what the value of the dataSnapshot looks like.

Comment: great! i get my name and description, but i also get `fetch data kotlin.Unit` i think , I'm passing something wrong as a guid : `fetchData(arguments?.getString("guid", "") ?: "")`

Comment: Your input parameter seems fine (though you may want to just not make the call if guid is null rather than make the call with the empty string). fetchData itself is just giving you kotlin.Unit because it doesn't return anything. You won't be able to return it directly since onDataChange is an asynchronous call